# how to reload/refresh a page on event in javascript in facebook?

Tags: javascript, facebook, refresh, reload

I am having this problem :

Whenever, some specific button is clicked my javascript function runs and does something. I want the function to refresh/reload the page as well.

I dont know how to do this.

Can anyone help, please ?

Thanks.

ahsan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
document.setLocation('url');
```

This should help.

Comment: in facebook, it doesnt work. I am guessing that facebook adds something before location and makes the line something crap.

Comment: I tried doing this : new Dialog().showMessage('new', '111');
   
   location.reload(true);
   
   new Dialog().showMessage('new', '222');
So, the output/function stops after showing the new dialog box '111' .. any idea, what can be done ? thanks